# CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition crashes with bad_alloc

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, core-text, core-foundation

I'm trying to get position of text in a line like this:

```
CFIndex Idx = CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition(line, pos);
```

But i get crash with the following stack trace. Why should there be a crash?

```
- libc++.1.dylib std::__throw_bad_alloc()
- CoreText std::__1::__split_buffer<TLine::CaretInfo, std::__1::allocator<TLine::CaretInfo>&>::__split_buffer(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<TLine::CaretInfo>&)
- CoreText void std::__1::vector<TLine::CaretInfo, std::__1::allocator<TLine::CaretInfo> >::__emplace_back_slow_path<TLine::CaretInfo>(TLine::CaretInfo&&)
- CoreText TLine::EnumerateCaretOffsets(std::__1::function<void (double, long, bool, bool*)>) const
- CoreText TLine::PositionToCharIndex(CGPoint) const
- CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition(line, pos);
```

Comment: Could you include more of your code leading up to the call to `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition`?

Comment: sorry i cant. I'm unable to repro the crash locally, the only thing i have is the crash report with above stack trace.